Is there evidence of Laban (the Genesis Laban) outside of the Bible?
I'm wanting to know not for the sake of evidence per say, but just if there is any extra-biblical reference or archeological stuff that is connected to Laban to help understand or learn more about him.
Please exclude anything that clearly is drawing off of the Bible (like apocryphal texts from Dead Sea Scrolls).

Nuzi tables seem to be now discredited as relevant evidence... but even these would be a circumstantial evidence at best (proving veracity of customs, but not the existence of actual person.)

Laban is mentioned in the Nuzi tablets?

No - as is already said in my previous comment, Nuzi tables were believed to provide evidence of the customs in the Patriarch's times being consistent with those described in the Bible for Laban interactions with Jacob. As far as I understand, this is the closest that we can get to Laban. But, of course, an absence of evidence is not an evidence of absence.
